# change web Url to another Url using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii, url-rewriting, centos

I have centos server, I want to see my websile url along with `/index.php` in the address bar.

When I'm trying to access my website `www.example.com`, I want to see the url of the webpage should be `www.example.com/index.php` in the address bar.

I hope it will work by configuring .htaccess file. I'm not familiar with .htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: but still it `shows www.example.com` in address bar

Comment: could you please tell what is the use of `^$` how its working. please.

Answer (score 0):

If index.php is in the DirectoryIndex list, you're doing a needless redirect/rewrite.

Comment: Ya, I know. but i want that url in my address bar.